# Как называется массив, в котором не могут повторяться элементы?

Tags: c#, терминология

Как называется массив, в котором не могут повторяться элементы, то есть, допустим, ты его заполняешь всем, но вот одинаковые элементы не дублируются и не записываются больше одного раза.

Comment: HashSet это называется

Comment: В математике это называется [множество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Множество), в информатике аналогично [множество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Множество_(тип_данных)). В .NET смотрите классы, реализующие интерфейс [ISet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)